# Where is the Blade wizard school detailed?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, content-identification

I have been using the "Fifth Edition Character Sheet" app and it mentions the “Blade” wizard school. The app says it gives this feature:

> 2/rest you can use a bonus action to assume a magical stance while not wearing a shield, heavy or medium armor (see rules)

Where can I get the full details on this class school of wizard called a Blade? It sounds interesting and I want to know if there is a PDF or book or something available to get more information.

Answer (score 11):

**The "Fifth Edition Character Sheet" app actually refers to the Bladesinger Arcane Tradition.**

The Bladesinger is a new Wizard Tradition detailed in the [Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide) by Wizards of the Coast. It can be found, specifically in page 141 of the said book.

It should be noted that this app labels weird names when presenting certain class options. Allow me to list a few examples:

- "The Undying" Warlock Patron is listed as "Undead"
- "Sun Soul" monks are listed as "Light"
- "Purple Dragon Knight" Fighters are listed as just "Knights"

Oddly, Swashbuckler and Mastermind rogues, Battlerager Barbarians, Arcana Clerics and Oath of the Crown Paladins are named correctly. To deal with these inconsistencies with the app, you have to have a firm grip of 5e class options, as even options like Sorcerer's Metamagic options, Warlock Eldritch Invocations, and a Battlemaster Fighter's maneuvers are all paraphrased and not listed verbatim.

You can take solace in the fact that the app has no homebrew or Unearthed Arcana added in it, so everything there is official material which can be easily found.

Comment: As a note, this may be related to the fact that only certain content is available in the SRD, and even then, a lot of the content in the SRD has proper names stripped out. For example, Mordenkainen's Magnificent Mansion simply becomes Magnificent Mansion. "Sun Soul" and "Purple Dragon" are region specific properties of WotC as well, and are likely stripped out for this reason.